# Emacs engine-mode returns engine/execute-search: Invalid format operation %%D

Tags: url, emacs

I have started using engine-mode for emacs and I love it. For some reason though the Amazon search engine does not work properly. I have used the same structure as advertised in the [github](https://github.com/hrs/engine-mode) website

```
(defengine amazon
"http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=%s")
```

and when I try to search for anything emacs returns a "engine/execute-search: Invalid format operation %%D" error. All the other search engines worked flawlessly, and I couldn't find anyone with the same complaint online. I assume there might be some issue with the % signs in URL's?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: What happens if you try with `"https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=%s"` instead?

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, it is working flawlessly now. It is strange that the wrong url is in the official github website. I guess they probably didn't test it? If you write the answer formally I will accept it.

Comment: I just found another search engine with the same problem. Mathworks
https://uk.mathworks.com/?s_tid=gn_logo Same thing. Just had to remove the text between the ? and & which had the percentage sign and it worked perfectly. Seems to be a common issue.

Comment: Yes, I guess the 'real' solution would be to see if the generated search query is different than what it should be - perhaps the string needs to be prepared/escaped in some way?  If so, this should be a github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting @VanLaser solution, just use `"https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?field-keywords=%s"`